# Jasmine toEqual for complex objects (mixed with functions)

Tags: jasmine, matcher

Currently, I have a function that sometimes return an object with some functions inside. When using `expect(...).toEqual({...})` it doesn't seem to match those complex objects. Objects having functions or the `File` class (from input type file), it just can't. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Vlad Magdalin pointed out in the comments, making the object to a JSON string, it can be as deep as it is, and functions and File/FileList class. Of course, instead of `toString()` on the function, it could just be called 'Function'

```js
function replacer(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
        v = v.toString();
    } else if (window['File'] && v instanceof File) {
        v = '[File]';
    } else if (window['FileList'] && v instanceof FileList) {
        v = '[FileList]';
    }
    return v;
}

beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers({
        toBeJsonEqual: function(expected){
            var one = JSON.stringify(this.actual, replacer).replace(/(\\t|\\n)/g,''),
                two = JSON.stringify(expected, replacer).replace(/(\\t|\\n)/g,'');

                return one === two;
            }
    });
});

expect(obj).toBeJsonEqual(obj2);
```

Comment: Please note that JSON.stringify doesn't guarantee property order! So comparing generated JSONs might cause random test failures. It depends on the underlying javascript runner how properties will be sorted. For example: tests might work when run in engineA (e.g. NodeJS), but then break in engineB (e.g. Firefox) or even in another engineA version. Or break randomly even when run in the same engine of the same version.

Answer (score 18):

Try the [Underscore _.isEqual()](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) function:

```
expect(_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)).toEqual(true);
```

If that works, you could create a [custom matcher](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers):

```
this.addMatchers({
    toDeepEqual: function(expected) {
        return _.isEqual(this.actual, expected);
    };
});
```

You can then write specs like the following:

```
expect(some_obj).toDeepEqual(expected_obj);
```

Comment: gives me the same result from `toEqual` => `Error: Expected { exception : Function, data : Function, proxy : Function, remote : Function, append_args : Function, set_args : Function, get_args : Function, remove : Function, make : Function, unmake : Function } to deep equal { exception : Function, data : Function, proxy : Function, remote : Function, append_args : Function, set_args : Function, get_args : Function, remove : Function, make : Function, unmake : Function }.`

Comment: Are the objects you are comparing composed only of functions?

Comment: in that particular case, yes, but sometimes I have classes along with plain objects and native wrappers, like the `File` and `FileList` classes

Comment: awesome that (JSON.stringify) works... I'll accept your answer after you accept the modification :)

Comment: actually, it didn't work, after checking the output of that function, it's showing as `{}`, which is clearly wrong, it seems it can't convert functions to string (like using `(function(){}).toString()`)

Comment: Is it important for you that the functions match? If so, what do you consider a match? Should two functions with the same code but different closures be considered equal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23431/discussion-between-vlad-magdalin-and-pocesar)

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is using node.js like myself, the following method is what I use in my Jasmine tests when I am only concerned with comparing the simple properties while ignoring all functions.  This method requires [json-stable-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify) which is used to sort the object properties prior to serializing.

**Usage:**

```
  var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');

  var obj1 = {
    func: function() {
    },
    str1: 'str1 value',
    str2: 'str2 value',
    nest1: {
    nest2: {
        val1:'value 1',
        val2:'value 2',
        someOtherFunc: function() {
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var obj2 = {
    str2: 'str2 value',
    str1: 'str1 value',
    func: function() {
    },
    nest1: {
      nest2: {
        otherFunc: function() {
        },
        val2:'value 2',
        val1:'value 1'
      }
    }
  };

  it('should compare object properties', function () {
    expect(stringify(obj1)).toEqual(stringify(obj2));
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Vlad Magdalin's answer, this worked in Jasmine 2:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toDeepEqual: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
      return {
        compare: function(actual, expected) {
          var result = {};
          result.pass = _.isEqual(actual, expected);
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

If you're using Karma, put that in the startup callback:

```
callback: function() {
  // Add custom Jasmine matchers.
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toDeepEqual: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
        return {
          compare: function(actual, expected) {
            var result = {};
            result.pass = _.isEqual(actual, expected);
            return result;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

  window.__karma__.start();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

here's how I did it using the `Jasmine 2` syntax.

I created a customMatchers module in `../support/customMatchers.js` (I like making modules).

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  Custom Jasmine matchers to make unit testing easier.
 */
module.exports = {
  // compare two functions.
  toBeTheSameFunctionAs: function(util, customEqualityTesters) {
    let preProcess = function(func) {
      return JSON.stringify(func.toString()).replace(/(\\t|\\n)/g,'');
    };

    return {
      compare: function(actual, expected) {
        return {
          pass: (preProcess(actual) === preProcess(expected)),
          message: 'The functions were not the same'
        };
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Which is then used in my test as follows:

```
"use strict";

let someExternalFunction = require('../../lib/someExternalFunction');
let thingBeingTested = require('../../lib/thingBeingTested');

let customMatchers = require('../support/customMatchers');

describe('myTests', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);

    let app = {
      use: function() {}
    };

    spyOn(app, 'use');
    thingBeingTested(app);
  });

  it('calls app.use with the correct function', function() {
    expect(app.use.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(app.use.calls.argsFor(0)).toBeTheSameFunctionAs(someExternalFunction);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two objects but ignore their functions, you can use the methods [`_.isEqualWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#isEqualWith) together with [`_.isFunction`](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#isFunction) from `lodash` as follows.

```
function ignoreFunctions(objValue, otherValue) {
  if (_.isFunction(objValue) && _.isFunction(otherValue)) {
    return true;
  }
}

it('check object equality but ignore their functions', () => {    
  ...
  expect(_.isEqualWith(actualObject, expectedObject, ignoreFunctions)).toBeTrue();
});
```