# Testing a loader in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is a test for a $resource with a loader

```
describe('Service: MultiCalculationsLoader', function(){

  beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

  var MultiCalculationLoader,
    mockBackend,
    calculation;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, Calculation, _MultiCalculationLoader_) {
    MultiCalculationLoader = _MultiCalculationLoader_;
    mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    calculation = Calculation;
  }));

  it('should load a list of calculation from a user', function(){
    mockBackend.expectGET('/api/user/600/calculation').respond([{id:5}]);

     var calculations;
     var mockStateParams = {
       userId: 600
     };
    var promise = new MultiCalculationLoader(mockStateParams);

    promise.then(function(res){
      calculations = res
    });

    expect(calculations).toBeUndefined();

    mockBackend.flush();

    expect(calculations).toEqual([{id:5}]);
  });

});
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
Expected [ { id : 5 } ] to equal [ { id : 5 } ].
Error: Expected [ { id : 5 } ] to equal [ { id : 5 } ].
    at null.<anonymous>
```

I don't get it. The two arrays are the same to me. Ideas anyone?

**Update**
Here's the implementation:

```
 .factory('Calculation', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/user/:userId/calculation/:calcId', {'calcId': '@calcId'});
  })
  .factory('MultiCalculationLoader', function (Calculation, $q) {
    return function ($stateParams) {
      var delay = $q.defer();
      Calculation.query( {userId: $stateParams.userId},function (calcs) {
        delay.resolve(calcs);
      }, function () {
        delay.reject('Unable to fetch calculations');
      });
      return delay.promise;
    };
  })
```

Comment: it seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/DLUaEEzBnyWOUudsaooG?p=preview

Comment: @KhanhTO Yeha but it's not working in my dev environment.

Comment: Can you show how your `MultiCalculationLoader` is implemented?

Comment: The implementation works. It's just my test that does not work.

Comment: I just suspect that there is an issue in your `MultiCalculationLoader` that causes the test to fail

Comment: Okey. I have added the loader in my question.

Comment: The url that you expect is different from the actual url: `expectGET('/api/user/600/calculations')` and `/api/user/:userId/calculation/:calcId'` (even when replaced with parameters)

Comment: @KhanhTO Sorry! I had updated my test since I posted. I have now updated the question so there is no s. So it is something else.

Comment: you have to call `MultiCalculationLoader({userId:600});` instead of `MultiCalculationLoader()`, see my answer.

Comment: Updated the test. Still same error.

Comment: you have to remove the `new`, just call `MultiCalculationLoader({userId:600});`

Comment: Tried it. No success.

Comment: I set up a plunk to try your case, it turns out that angular automatically adds 2 properties to your response. See my updated answer with picture and demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you expect is different from the actual url. I guess you need something like this:

```
it('should load a list of calculation from a user', function(){
    //remove the 's' from 'calculations'
    mockBackend.expectGET('/api/user/600/calculation').respond([{id:5}]);

    var calculations;
    var promise = MultiCalculationLoader({userId:600}); //userId = 600
    promise.then(function(res){
      calculations = res
    });

    expect(calculations).toBeUndefined();

    mockBackend.flush();

    expect(calculations).toEqual([{id:5}]);
  });
```

There is another problem that angular automatically adds 2 properties to the response:

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/gIHolGd85SLswzv5VZ1E?p=preview

It's kind of the same problem as: [AngularJS + Jasmine: Comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487510/angularjs-jasmine-comparing-objects)

This is really a problem with angular $resource when angular convert the response to resource objects. In order to verify responses from $resource, you could try `angular.equals`

```
expect(angular.equals(calculations,[{id:5},{id:6}])).toBe(true);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PrZhk2hkvER2XTBIW7yv?p=preview

You could also write a custom matcher:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function() {
        return {
          compare: function(actual, expected) {
            return {
              pass: angular.equals(actual, expected)
            };
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });
```

And use it:

```
expect(calculations).toEqualData([{id:5},{id:6}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vNfRmc6R1G69kg0DyjZf?p=preview

Comment: Isn't it a bit messy? Maybe I'm totally off here but how about using angular.toJson? I think that removes the "junk" from the array?

Comment: @user1572526: I found out that we could use `angular.equals` for that. `angular.equals` will strip out functions and internal implementation details of angular (like hashkey) when testing

Comment: @user1572526: you could also write a custom matcher. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine equality selectors can be too specfic sometimes when you just wanna check for equaity.

I have never seen it with the toEqual() method when comparing objects or arrays, but def with the toBe() method.

Try to replace toEqual() with toMatch().

Also in the unit test I recommend using a constant value that you can pass in the response and the matchers/equal/toBe's.

```
describe('Service: MultiCalculationsLoader', function(){

  beforeEach(module('clientApp'));

  var MultiCalculationLoader,
    mockBackend,
    calculation,
    VALUE = [{id:5}];

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, Calculation, _MultiCalculationLoader_) {
    MultiCalculationLoader = _MultiCalculationLoader_;
    mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    calculation = Calculation;
  }));

  it('should load a list of calculation from a user', function(){
    mockBackend.expectGET('/api/user/600/calculations').respond(VALUE);

    var calculations;
    var promise = MultiCalculationLoader();
    promise.then(function(res){
      calculations = res
    });

    expect(calculations).toBeUndefined();

    mockBackend.flush();

    expect(calculations).toEqual(VALUE);
  });

});
```

Using this approach I think the .toEqual will actually work.

Our approach:

Before Block:

```
httpBackend.when('JSONP', PATH.url + 'products?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&category=123').respond(CATEGORIES[0]);
```

Test:

```
describe('Category Method', function () {

        it('Should return the first category when the method category is called', function () {
            var result = '';

            service.category(123).then(function(response) {
                result = response;
            });

            httpBackend.flush();
            expect(result).toEqual(CATEGORIES[0]);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work with constant value. But it did work with toMatch(). Thx!

Comment: hmmm weird - its the exact approach we have in our unit tests... Try maybe returning VALUE[0] and testing for equality on that as well.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the expectGET vs when methods and how they return data....

Comment: "toMatch" seems to accept anything. So it did not work. Back to square one. Any other idea?

Comment: you got 3 choices - toMatch, toBe, toEqual

Answer (score 0):

you can try change toEqual() with toEqualData()

```
expect(calculations).toEqualData([{id:5}]);
```

Comment: Could not find the "toEqualData" function?