# Jasmine Error on same string, 'Expected .. to equal ...'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm getting this error, but I've checked and tested the strings and they are exactly the same:

```
Expected { $$state : { status : 1, value : { customerNumber : 'customerNumber', name : 'name', userId : 'buId', customerType : 'type', address : 'displayAddress' } } } 
to equal { $$state : { status : 1, value : { customerNumber : 'customerNumber', name : 'name', userId : 'buId', customerType : 'type', address : 'displayAddress' } } }.
Error: Expected { $$state : { status : 1, value : { customerNumber : 'customerNumber', name : 'name', userId : 'buId', customerType : 'type', address : 'displayAddress' } } } to equal { $$state : { status : 1, value : { customerNumber : 'customerNumber', name : 'name', userId : 'buId', customerType : 'type', address : 'displayAddress' } } }.
        at C:/customerServiceSpec.js:70
```

The only thing I can notice is there is a full stop at the end, but I think Jasmine is adding that in the response. Here is my test code:

```
describe('CustomerService', () => {
    var mockUserSession: any = {};
    var testService any = {};
    var $q: ng.IQService;
    var createCustomerDetailsService;
    var customerDetailsService;
    var createResolvedPromise;
    var createRejectedPromise;
    var resolvePromises;

    var testResponse = {
        customers: {
            displayCustomerNumber: 'customerNumber',
            name: 'name',
            id: 'id',
            type: 'type',
            displayAddress: 'displayAddress'
        }
    };

    var serviceResponse={
        $$state: {
            status: 1,
            value: {
                customerNumber: 'customerNumber',
                name: 'name',
                id: 'id',
                customerType: 'type',
                address:'displayAddress'
            }
        }
    };

    var rootScope;

    beforeEach(() => {
        module('app.customer');

        inject(( _$q_, $injector) => {
            this.$q = _$q_;
            rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            createResolvedPromise = (result) => {
                return () => {
                    return this.$q.when(result);
                };
            };

            resolvePromises = () => {
                rootScope.$digest();
            };

            createCustomerDetailsService = () => {
                return new app.customer.CustomerService(
                    testService);
            };
        });

    });

    it('WILL search by customer ID and return a customers details', () => {
        var searchResponsePromise;

        testService.getCustomerDetails = jasmine.createSpy("getCustomerDetails").and.callFake(createResolvedPromise(testResponse));
        customerDetailsService = createCustomerDetailsService();
        searchResponsePromise = customerDetailsService.getCustomerDetails('12345678');
        resolvePromises();

        expect(searchResponsePromise).toEqual(serviceResponse);
    });
});
```

And here is my service:

```
public getCustomerDetails(customerID:string): ng.IPromise<ICustomerDetails> {
    return this.testService.getCustomerDetails(customerID).then((customerResponse:ICustomerResult) => {

        var customer = customerResponse.customers;

        var customerDetailsResult:ICustomerDetails = {
            customerNumber: customer.displayCustomerNumber,
            name: customer.name,
            userId: customer.buId,
            customerType: customer.type,
            address: customer.displayAddress
        };

        return customerDetailsResult;
    });
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm confused too, but I don't see the `status` field in the return of your getCustomerDetails() function, even though it surely appears in the Jasmine output

Comment: It may happen that you key is not getting identified as it contains special characters please try adding double or single quotes and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Gabriel and Jayant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to the fact that json objects are actually different instances of objects, but they contain the same data. You need to do something like this:

`expect(angular.equals(searchResponsePromise, serviceResponse)).toBe(true);`

Comment: That nailed it. Thank you SO much @Diana R !!

Answer (score -1):

See [AngularJS + Jasmine: Comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487510/angularjs-jasmine-comparing-objects) for the preferred way of doing this. Essentially, you want to use `expect(...).toEqual(...)` instead of `expect(...).toBe(...)`. `toEqual()` performs a deep comparison.

The advantage to doing this over the accepted answer is the error for a failed assertion with `toBe(true)` will simply say something along the lines of, `expected false to be true`, which isn't enough information to fix the problem.

The deep comparison performed by `toEqual()` will result in an assertion error containing both the expected and actual objects, serialized as strings. It makes it much nicer and easier to fix the problem. :)