# Jasmine fails in toEqual with objects that look the same

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've read other threads, tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work.

Test:

```
it("parses string array", function(){
    var usArr = ["integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer", "dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration"];
    var newJson = [
        {
            fname : "integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer",
            con : "ImageViewer.main",
            type : "integer",
            vars : [{name : "RawBuffer"}]
        },
        {
            fname : "dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration",
            con : "ImageViewer.main",
            type : "dio",
            vars : [{name : "performUnitCalibration"}]
        }
    ];
    expect(JFactory.parseToJSON(usArr)).toEqual(newJson);
})
```

Error message:

```
Expected 

'[{"fname":"integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer",
"com":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"integer",
"vars":[{"name":"RawBuffer"}]},
{"fname":"dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration",
"com":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"dio",
"vars":[{"name":"performUnitCalibration"}]}]' 

to equal 
'[{"fname":"integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer",
"con":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"integer",
"vars":[{"name":"RawBuffer"}]},
{"fname":"dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration",
"con":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"dio",
"vars":[{"name":"performUnitCalibration"}]}]'.


Error: Expected 

'[{"fname":"integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer",
"com":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"integer",
"vars":[{"name":"RawBuffer"}]},
{"fname":"dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration",
"com":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"dio",
"vars":[{"name":"performUnitCalibration"}]}]' 

to equal 
'[{"fname":"integer.ImageViewer.main.RawBuffer",
"con":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"integer",
"vars":[{"name":"RawBuffer"}]},
{"fname":"dio.ImageViewer.main.performUnitCalibration",
"con":"ImageViewer.main",
"type":"dio",
"vars":[{"name":"performUnitCalibration"}]}]'.
```

I've tried to JSON stringify both objects, tried toBe and tried:

```
expect(_.isEqual(JFactory.parseToJSON(usArr), newJson)).toEqual(true);
```

as suggested here: [Jasmine toEqual for complex objects (mixed with functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541287/jasmine-toequal-for-complex-objects-mixed-with-functions)
that gives me:
ReferenceError: _ is not defined

I'm completely lost as the objects seem to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"com":"ImageViewer.main",

"con":"ImageViewer.main",
```

your are writing `com` in one and `con` in the other, they are definetly not equal.

Comment: Ahh, the cons of being a legally blind programmer show itself yet again. Thank you.

Comment: I evaluted the strings in node,and did `JSON.stringify(x)===JSON.stringify(y)` since it returned false,it meant you had a typo somewhere in the code, dont worry,it's hard to spot even for people with good eyesight,cheers.