# How to spy on constructor using Jasmine and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jasmine, mocking, spy

Is there a way how to spy on constructor using Jasmine and Typescript?

Proposed solutions in question [Spying on a constructor using Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347631/spying-on-a-constructor-using-jasmine) do not work because [TypeScript does not expose global declarations on `window`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19816).

Here is my use case:

```
// higher-order function returns validation function with max length
const maxLengthValidator = maxLength => value => value.length > maxLength;

class Book {
  // will be a different function instance each time the Book object is
  // created causing the following test to fail
  nameValidator = maxLengthValidator(42);
  name = null;
  constructor (name) { this.name = name; }
}

class Library {
  persons = [];
  storeBook (book) { this.persons.push(book); }
  createBook (name) { this.storeBook(new Book(name)); }
}
```

Failing test:

```
it('createBook passes new book with provided name to storeBook', () => {
  const lib = new Library();
  spyOn(lib, 'storeBook');
  lib.createBook('Start with Why');
  expect(lib.storeBook).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Book('Start with Why'));
  // Result: Expected spy storeBook to have been called with
  // [ Book({ name: 'Start with Why', nameValidator: Function }) ]
  // but actual calls were
  // [ Book({ name: 'Start with Why', nameValidator: Function }) ]
});
```

In the test, I don't really care what constructor does. I only need to verify that it has been called with the right parameter. That even sounds like a right use case for a mock.

Comment: You're spying on it correctly. However the test is failing because it is called with a different `Book` instance, even if their "values" are the same.

Comment: But Jasmine test passed even for a different `Book` instance until I used the higher-order function. It seems to compare values even if it is a different instance. Is there a way how to write the test with a single `Book` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Two functions can be compared using their `toString` value. You can either add a custom equality tester or add new matcher.

### Adding custom equality tester

```js
function replacer(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
        v = v.toString();
    }
    return v;
}

function stringifyEquality(a, b) {
    try {
        return JSON.stringify(a, replacer) === JSON.stringify(b, replacer) ? true : undefined;
    } catch (e) {
        return undefined
    }
}

beforeAll(() => {
    jasmine.addCustomEqualityTester(stringifyEquality);
});

it('createBook passes new book with provided name to storeBook', () => {
    const lib = new Library();
    spyOn(lib, 'storeBook');
    lib.createBook('Start with Why');
    expect(lib.storeBook.calls.mostRecent().args).toEqual([new Book('Start with Why')]);
});
```

### Adding custom matcher

```
function replacer(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'function') {
        v = v.toString();
    }
    return v;
}

beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toBeJsonEqual: function(expected){
            var one = JSON.stringify(this.actual, replacer).replace(/(\\t|\\n)/g,''),
                two = JSON.stringify(expected, replacer).replace(/(\\t|\\n)/g,'');

                return one === two;
            }
    });
});

expect(obj).toBeJsonEqual(obj2);
```

links: [question 14541287 (pocesar's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543886/8719359)